# wrong in json parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

please help me to find the error in this code.
I want to get some data from remote server (php & mysql) by json then parsing it 
the problem is that **result** returns **null** but it is supposed to return **name** at this link :
http://codeincloud.tk/json_android_example.php

```
package com.shadatv.shada;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class canticlesActivity extends Activity {

    TextView httpStuff;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject json;

    final static String URL = "http://codeincloud.tk/json_android_example.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.canticles);

        httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        new Read().execute("name");
    }

    public JSONObject lastTweet() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
            return last;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                json = lastTweet();
                return json.getString(params[0]);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ahmed .. " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            httpStuff.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: could you paste some LogCat output like stackStraces?

Comment: why are you trying to parse the Json object in a JSONArray ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy and past now it is working.
i changed JSONObject last =new JSONObject(data);

because http://codeincloud.tk/json_android_example.php retuning an JSONObject

```
package com.shadatv.shada;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class canticlesActivity extends Activity {

    TextView httpStuff;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject json;

    final static String URL = "http://codeincloud.tk/json_android_example.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.canticles);

        httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        new Read().execute("name");
    }

    public JSONObject lastTweet() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);

            JSONObject last =  new JSONObject(data);
            return last;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                json = lastTweet();
                return json.getString(params[0]);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ahmed .. " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            httpStuff.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: there is another question, what have i to do if i want to receive json array like that : http://dt-works.com/ags/shadatv/canticles/android_data

how can i modify it ?

Answer (score 1):

parse current json String as :

```
 HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
 String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
 // convert data to json object
 JSONObject last =new JSONObject(data);
```

because current webservice retuning an `JSONObject` only instead of `JSONArray`

Answer (score 1):

Your URL provides the following data:

> {"name":"Froyo","version":"Android 2.2"}

The chunk of code parsing the JSON is the following:

> ```
>         JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
>         JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
> ```

That makes the assumption that the JSON document you're reading is an Array instead of an Object. (Either is valid JSON, but the document you're fetching is quite clearly an Object). Web service calls may not always be returning one or the other so you'll have to take care that you're parsing against the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use GSON Library which is much simpler then doing manual parsing.

Link for the library is : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/